# Import XML workspace into enterprise geodatabase with different spatial reference system

Tags: esri-geodatabase, xml, geodatabase-xml

An XML document with the schema definition of a geodatabase (ESRI Format) is available to be restored in another server (UPDM definition 2018).
The definition was created with the spatial reference 102968 (NAD_1983_2011_Michigan_GeoRef_Meters). I t is required to apply this schema to a brand new geodatabase but using the spatial reference WGS84.

The tool [Import XML workspace](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/import-xml-workspace-document.htm) does not have the option to change the spatial reference.

This document is a one-line xml with a huge amount of data. It is quite cumbersome to change the spatial reference, moreover if you do not have the knowledge of the xml schema.

Is there a way to automatically change the spatial reference either in the XML or in the import process?

Answer (score -1):

Using Enteprise Architect sparx System, we can manipulate the XML file before loading to the new GDB.

Comment: Can you show an example how?

Comment: https://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/demos/geospatial/how-to-design-a-geodatabase.html